# swift 2: Sprite tilting effect

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Looking for a method to tilt a sprite upwards on the right side when tapping the screen (like in flappy bird) Like a start of a rotation that returns to the place it were. I will use this as an effect of going faster then the sprite normally does.

I'll add the code I got so far below:

```
var player = SKSpriteNode()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    let playerTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "player")
    player = SKSpriteNode(texture: playerTexture)
    player.position = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 80)
    player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: playerTexture, size: playerTexture.size())
    player.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = true
    self.addChild(player)
 }

   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {


 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Like a start of a rotation that returns to the place it were."?

Comment: I mean it begins lifting updwards on the right side. The rotation was a bad explanation

Comment: Maybe an SKAction that adjusts the `zRotation` of the sprite?